# How to Update the Content of a div in a Separate Function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, sorting

I am very new to JavaScript, so I apologize if this question is worded poorly or if the answer is obvious. I decided to take up a sorting visualizer project as a practice. The one I am currently working on is based on [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pFXYym4Wbkc&t=808s&ab_channel=Cl%C3%A9mentMihailescu) by Clément Mihailescu.

In my program, I have my render function which takes an array with random values, and uses array.map() to generate columns of bars that have a height according to the value, and a color for the bars:

```
render() {
    const {array} = this.state;

    return (
      <div className="array-container">
        {array.map((value, idx) => (
          <div
            className="array-bar"
            key={idx}
            style={{
              backgroundColor: PRIMARY_COLOR,
              height: `${value}px`,
            }}></div>
        ))}
        <button onClick={() => this.resetArray()}>Generate New Array</button>
        <button onClick={() => this.mergeSort()}>Merge Sort</button>
        <button onClick={() => this.quickSort()}>Quick Sort</button>
        <button onClick={() => this.heapSort()}>Heap Sort</button>
        <button onClick={() => this.bubbleSort()}>Bubble Sort</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

At the bottom, I have some buttons that perform the specific sorting algorithm on my array bars and a "Generate New Array" button. The result ends up [looking like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0HKIO.png)

My problem is that my QuickSort algorithm ends up changing the colors of my bars to purple to indicate that the array has been sorted, but I want to be able to change them back to their original color whenever my "Generate New Array" button is pressed. Right now, my "reset array" function generates a new array with random numbers and then sets the state of my main array equal to that:

```
 resetArray() {
    const array = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_ARRAY_BARS; i++) {
      array.push(randomIntFromInterval(5, 400));
    }  
    this.setState({array});  
 }
```

So this generates my new array successfully, but the color is not being updated

I am assuming that to change the color of the array bars back the way I want, I should generate my bars inside of this resetArray function, and then simply call it in my original render. The problem is my limited understanding of JavaScript is making this seemingly simple fix rather difficult. Syntax wise I just don't know what the best approach for this would be. If anyone could lead me in the right direction I would greatly appreciate it. Sorry for the long post, I wanted to be thorough in describing my problem.

**Update Describing QuickSort Algorithm**

This portion of the code isn't very great and could probably be done more efficiently. For my QuickSort call, I generate a separate "animations" array for my changes in bar color/value. I loop through this array, and depending on whether I reach a string (new color) or a number (new value) I edit my array index accordingly.

```
  quickSort() {

    const animations = getQuickSortAnimations(this.state.array);
    
      for (let i = 0; i < animations.length; i++){
        const arrayBars = document.getElementsByClassName('array-bar');
        let barIndex;
        let barStyle;
        // break in the case of array being out of bounds
        if (animations[i][0] >= this.state.array.length) { break; }

          // switch statement performs either height change or color change
          // depending on which is passed through to animations
          switch(typeof animations[i][1]){
            // color change
            case "string":
              barIndex = animations[i][0];
              barStyle = arrayBars[barIndex].style;
              setTimeout(() => {
                barStyle.backgroundColor = animations[i][1];
              }, i * ANIMATION_SPEED_MS);
              break;
              //height change
            case "number":
              barIndex = animations[i][0];
              barStyle = arrayBars[barIndex].style;
              setTimeout(() => {
                barStyle.height = `${animations[i][1]}px`
              }, i * ANIMATION_SPEED_MS);
          }
     }
```

In the beginning, I set my animations array equal to "getQuickSortAnimations", where my actual algorithm is taking place in a separate file. This is where I perform the pushes to my animations array that visually sorts the array bars:

```
export function getQuickSortAnimations (array) {
    const animations = [];
    if (array.length <= 1) { return array; }
    quickSort(array, 0, array.length-1, animations)
    return animations;
}

function quickSort (array, lowIndex, highIndex, animations){
    if (lowIndex >= highIndex) { 
        animations.push([lowIndex, 'purple']);
        return; 
    }
    let pivot = array[highIndex];
    let leftPtr = partition(array, lowIndex, highIndex, pivot, animations);
    quickSort(array, lowIndex, leftPtr-1, animations);
    quickSort (array, leftPtr+1, highIndex, animations);
}

function partition (array, lowIndex, highIndex, pivot, animations){
    let leftPtr = lowIndex;
    let rightPtr = highIndex-1;
    // Coloring our first instance of leftPtr and our Pivot(highIndex)
    animations.push([highIndex, 'yellow']);
    animations.push([leftPtr, 'red']);
    animations.push([rightPtr, 'red']);
    while (leftPtr < rightPtr) {
        while ((array[leftPtr] <= pivot) && (leftPtr < rightPtr)){
            // Send rightPtr to animations once to decolor
            animations.push([leftPtr, 'turquoise']);
            leftPtr++;
            // Send new leftPtr to animations to color new array bar
            animations.push([leftPtr, 'red']);
        }
        while ((array[rightPtr] >= pivot) && (leftPtr < rightPtr)){
            // Send rightPtr to animations once to decolor
            animations.push([rightPtr, 'turquoise']);
            rightPtr--;
            // Send new rightPtr to animations to color new array bar
            animations.push([rightPtr, 'red']);
        }
        // temp variable holds the value of our leftPtr index while we perform swap
        let temp = array[leftPtr];
        // swap our leftPtr with our rightPtr in animations
        animations.push([leftPtr, array[rightPtr]]);
        // swap our rightPtr with our leftPtr in animations using temp
        animations.push([rightPtr, temp]);
        // same swap as above but with the our actual array
        [array[leftPtr], array[rightPtr]] = [array[rightPtr], array[leftPtr]];
    }
    animations.push([highIndex, 'turquoise']);
    if (array[leftPtr] > array[highIndex]) {
        // temp variable holds the value of our leftPtr index while we perform swap
        let temp = array[leftPtr];
        // swap our leftPtr with our highIndex in animations
        animations.push([leftPtr, array[highIndex]]);
        // swap our highIndex with our leftPtr in animations using temp
        animations.push([highIndex, temp]);
        // same swap as above but with the our actual array
        [array[leftPtr], array[highIndex]] = [array[highIndex], array[leftPtr]];
        animations.push([leftPtr, 'purple']);
    }
    else {
        leftPtr = highIndex;
        animations.push([leftPtr, 'purple']);
    }
    return leftPtr;
}
```

Comment: How does your QuickSort affects the state? Can you add its code also so we can see? If you can add a bit complete code so we can reproduce and debug - it will be helpful. Or codesandbox, for example.

Comment: @SergeySosunov Thank you for the quick response, I have added my QuickSort call and the algorithm to my original post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so with react (or angular) never try to manipulate DOM outside of the react lifecycle, `document.getElementsByClassName` works in your case for changing color, but to change it back you will need to do it manually with same method which is not what you have to do with react. What you need to do is this:

Prepare the data to render, complete one, not only the array of numbers, but the array of objects {value, bgColor (for example}}, so each entry in the array will have all the data that it needs to render, asuming each of the items will have a different color.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  const arr = [1, 4, 85, 0, 1, 3, 5, 6, 4, 7, 1, 32, 1, 56, 84];
  const arrayToRender = this.getArrayToRender(arr, PRIMARY_COLOR);

  this.state = {
    array: arr,
    arrayToRender: arrayToRender
  };
}

getArrayToRender(array, color) {
  return array.map((x) => {
    return { value: x, bgColor: color };
  });
}
```

And change the rendering method to something like this:

```
render() {
  const { arrayToRender } = this.state;

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="array-container">
        {arrayToRender.map((x, idx) => (
          <div
            className="array-bar"
            key={idx}
            style={{
              backgroundColor: x.bgColor, // <- Here!
              height: `${x.value}px`
            }}
          ></div>
        ))}
      </div>
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => this.resetColor()}>Reset Color</button>
        <button onClick={() => this.resetArray()}>Generate New Array</button>
        <button onClick={() => this.mergeSort()}>Merge Sort</button>
        <button onClick={() => this.quickSort()}>Quick Sort</button>
        <button onClick={() => this.heapSort()}>Heap Sort</button>
        <button onClick={() => this.bubbleSort()}>Bubble Sort</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Notice i added a "Reset Color" button

```
resetColor() {
  // You can mutate state objects as is (dangerous)
  this.state.arrayToRender.forEach((x) => (x.bgColor = PRIMARY_COLOR));
  // But you need to re-set the state to make react reflect the changes
  this.setState((prev) => ({ ...prev }));
}
```

Also, the `quickSort` method will also need a little changes in order to not use DOM functions.

```
quickSort() {
  const animations = getQuickSortAnimations(this.state.array);

  for (let i = 0; i < animations.length; i++) {
    const curr = this.state.arrayToRender[animations[i][0]];
    switch (typeof animations[i][1]) {
      case "string":
        setTimeout(() => {
          curr.bgColor = animations[i][1];
          this.setState((prev) => ({ ...prev }));
        }, i * ANIMATION_SPEED_MS);
        break;
      case "number":
        setTimeout(() => {
          curr.value = animations[i][1];
          this.setState((prev) => ({ ...prev }));
        }, i * ANIMATION_SPEED_MS);
        break;
      default:
        console.error("Welp");
        break;
    }
  }
  // This will reset colors to default one after algo run + 2 sec
  const totalDelay = animations.length * ANIMATION_SPEED_MS + 2000; // added 2 seconds
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.resetColor();
  }, totalDelay);
}
```

[image: Edit React basic class component (forked)]

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I don't think I would have been able to figure this out on my own